# What is it called when you ride a bmx like a unicycle?

Tags: bmx, terminology, tricks

[image: bmx trick; straddling head tube, feet on pedals, hands on front wheel posts]

I was looking around a bit on YouTube and found a video for a footjam decade... which is pretty cool, in my opinion. However, in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SUAxIJDQ9U) at 2:44 he rides the bike like a unicycle, straddling the head tube with feet on the pedals... which is freaking cool. What would that even be called?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Guessing it is because it is offtopic, and in fact is best answered on one of the BMX trick forums on the web.

Comment: The FAQ seems pretty specific - "for people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles" ... though Meta doesn't specifically say "no trick questions," only to avoid chit chat. Meta also suggests that BMX is welcome and, as it is primarily racing and tricks, there should be some provision for these types of questions (i.e. how to ask questions about tricks.)

Comment: This is what I'm referencing: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/91/bmx-on-bicycles

Comment: You don't need a BMX to do that. This trick has probably been around since before BMXs existed. Any name is most likely something that's been created after the fact, and most people who did it first probably just called it riding a bike like a unicycle.  Anyway, check out Quicksilver for an early example (1986). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIwMGkqa6Sw

Comment: @WTHarper - I reckoned it wasn't a question about a trick, or how to ride, but purely a naming convention, which is easily googled. However Kibbee gave a good answer, so all's well :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I wasn't able to find a result on Google, and even with Kibbee's answer I was only able to find two or three things.

Comment: No, not so easily googled IMO

Comment: Both [BMX](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/91/8) *and* [unicycle](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/659/8) questions are completely on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this site on [artisitic cycling](http://www.rc09-noppenberg.de/homepagekrf/RC09_Webordner/4Infos/2Kunstrad/artistic_bicycle.htm) they refer to a trick called a "head-tube wheelie" which is probably a good name for it. BMX enthusiasts may have a different name for it, but that's essentially what it is.   I was also able to find this other site referring to [headtube wheelies](http://gonztronic.blogspot.ca/2009/12/headtube-wheelies.html).  Also, this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx_EwPCFdyg) refers to it as a headtube seated wheelie, and headtube backwheel riding.

After some [Googling](http://pedalbmx.com/posts/view/94179/spinning-forwards-death-trucks/page:2) with the help of @dotjoe's answer, I've found that this trick is referred to a "Pedalling Death Truck" or a "Blender".  There's also a trick called the "forwards spinning deathtruck" which is pretty much the same thing except the rider faces the other way around (at least as I understand it).

Answer (score 2):

The bmx name for the trick would probably be a pedaling death truck. A normal death truck is that same position, but with the feet on the back pegs. As you can imagine, that would leave you fairly stretched out and it'd be a nasty position to bail from.

Comment: It would probably be quite difficult on a BMX as most (all?) BMXs aren't fixed gear. In artistic cycling, bikes are always fixed gear and this position allows you to control it pretty much like a unicycle.

Comment: Difficult? That'd be an understatement! There are no fixed gears in bmx. Just getting into that position, let alone controlling the balance point...much respect to Terry Adams.

Comment: Giving you an upvote, seems like "pedalling death truck" is a common name for it.  Another term used is "Blender".  I've incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: Blender makes sense...kinda looks like an old school egg beater. lol